# Asp.net Web Api 2 OWIN self hosted, high CPU, what is the average compute load I should expect?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services, azure-application-insights

I built a set of 3 APIs using Asp.net **Web Api 2**, self-hosted using **OWIN** in an Azure Cloud service **Worker role**.
The Worker Role is exposed to the internet with a custom domain.

Each API has a single controller, doing some normal dictionary operations, table calls and **Azure Redis calls**. 1 request on two just do a single Redis call and return in around **10ms**. 
The average call when going through all the API code is **150ms**.
The answer is a JSON object of around **10k** in size.

Everything works fine, but I have a problem.

I'm having around **25 peaks connections per second** and no more than 2 Million requests per day, and I can barely get the CPU below **40%** with **3 Azure D2_V2 (2 cores , 8GB RAM)** instances running.
I'm in trouble because I'm spending almost 1.5k$ a month for an Api serving just 15-25 calls per second.
If I remove or scale down an instance, the **CPU go up to 55-60%,** Redis and Azure table calls slows down a lot and an API request takes 3- 5 seconds to get back.

I tried everything at the best of my abilities, I thought could be some bots or DDos attack, so I installed the nuget package WebApi Throttle, set a maximum of 1 requests per IP per second.
Nothing changed.

I reviewed all the code configuration to cut unoptimized parts, but 1 call in 2 just call redis and get back and the others are very clean and simple C# returning in 150ms with 2 azure table calls + 1 azure queue set.

The **API Controllers** are **async**, everything is async.

I enabled Profiling, the CPU is high in the main azure process, and the Redis Get method, nothing else relevant here, no bottlenecks.
I enabled Diagnostics, no errors.

I installed **Application Insights**, and here I see something strange that cannot tell if it is normal or not.

I see this IP: **13.88.23.0** doing thousands requests to the APIs with querystring values generally used in normal requests. A lot of them fail.
This IP is Azure itself, why is calling the Api? 
Some of these requests are stuck for minutes, I can see that from the Application insights panel, it's always the same IP.

Then I see the remaining logs, dependencies etc,nothing relevant.

Apart from that , **what could I do to understand the problem?**
I can't think is normal to consume so many CPU resources for an API with just 2 Million calls a day, or not?

Is there an additional profiling technique I could use?

Based on your experience, how many API calls should I expect to serve with 3 dual core 8GB RAM servers in normal conditions? (assuming there is something wrong in my configuration)

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I separated the API in two cloud services, 2 in one and 1 in another.
I still see in Application Insights calls from another IP belonging to Microsoft.
I suppose this is normal, probably Application insights cannot detect the real IP of the client since is a Worker Role and show the internal one.

But the problem of having to use so much power for so few calls remain.
Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Its all depends on how your application is perform? analyze which part taking CPU?